# WPF pass a DataContext to my UserControl inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl with two ContentTemplates:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabSelector}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

And my two templates are two user controls:

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserListTemplate">
            <uc:UserList />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserContentTemplate">
            <uc:User />
        </DataTemplate>

        <uc:TabSelector x:Key="TabSelector" UserListTemplate="{StaticResource UserListTemplate}" UserContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserContentTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I'm setting the DataContext in the XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewUsers />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The TabControl bind is working, showing all the tabs as I add/remove from the collection, but how do I get the DataContext in my UserControls? The DataContext is always null when the UserControl is started.

Comment: Access it in the DataContextChanged event.

Comment: @FreddyFlares Ah, that worked, thank you. It makes sense and helped me understand the cycle of control creation, first it's created without the DataContext, then it's set.

Answer (score 3):

The binding issue for a template is that once rendered as individual control will, *depending on the control* find its parent's data context, not from the visual tree but from its logical tree.

So the best bet is bind to the visual parent's datacontext via a `RelativeSource` direct binding such as:

```
{Binding TabName, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type TabControl }}}
```

or more likely:

```
   {Binding DataContext.TabName, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type TabControl }}}
```